# Intersect and Merge Arbitrary Maps by Id in Scala

Tags: scala

After reading two JSON files, I have the following two maps:

```
val m1 = Map("events" -> List(Map("id" -> "Beatles", "when" -> "Today"), Map("id"->"Elvis", "when"->"Tomorrow")))
val m2 = Map("events" -> List(Map("id" -> "Beatles", "desc"-> "The greatest band"), Map("id"->"BeachBoys","desc"-> "The second best band")))
```

I want to merge them in a generic way (without referencing the specific structure of these two particular maps) such that the result would be:

```
val m3 = Map("events" -> List(Map("id" -> "Beatles", "when" -> "Today", "desc"->"The greatest band")))
```

That is, first **intersect** by id and then **join** (*both on the same depth level*). It would be fine if it only works for a max depth of one as in this example (but of course, a fully recursive solution that could handle arbitrarily nested lists of maps / maps would be even better). This needs to be done in a complete generic way (otherwise it would be trivial), as the keys (like "events", "id", "when", ...) in both source JSON file will change.

I tried the (standard) Monoid/Semigroup addition in Scalaz/ Cats, however, this of course only concatenates the list elements and does not intersect/join.

```
val m3 = m1.combine(m2) // Cats
// Map(events -> List(Map(id -> Beatles, when -> Today), Map(id -> Elvis, when -> Tomorrow), Map(id -> Beatles, desc -> The greatest band), Map(id -> BeachBoys, desc -> The second best band)))
```

EDIT: The only assumption of the map structure is that there might be an "id" field. If it is present, then intersect and finally join.

Some background: I have two kind of JSON files. One with static information (e.g. a description of a band) and one with dynamic information (e.g. the date of the next concert). After reading the files, I get the two maps as presented above. I want to avoid to exploit the specific structure of the JSON files (e.g. by creating a domain model via case classes) as there are different scenarios with completely different source file structures which are likely subject to change and hence I don't want to create a dependency to this file structures in source code. Therefore, I need a generic way to merge these two maps.

Comment: Some clarification might be in order. You say "without referencing the specific structure," but after that, "first intersect by id." So we know/assume each `Map` is supposed to have an `id` key? Also, what does this join look like: `Map(id->A, xd->X)` and `Map(id->A, xd->Y)`?

Comment: Yes, you are right, that was unclear! There is a there is a field "id" (with a parameterizable field name).

Answer (score 0):

So you have these two maps.

```
val m1 = Map("events" -> List(Map("id" -> "Beatles", "when" -> "Today"), Map("id"->"Elvis", "when"->"Tomorrow")))
val m2 = Map("events" -> List(Map("id" -> "Beatles", "desc"-> "The greatest band"), Map("id"->"BeachBoys","desc"-> "The second best band")))
```

And, it looks like you are trying to group `events` and form `event` groups with id.

Your domain model can represented with following case classes.

```
case class EventDetails(title: String, desc: String)

case class Event(subjectId: String, eventDetails: EventDetails)

case class EventGroup(subjectId: String, eventDetailsList: List[EventDetails])
```

Lets convert out Maps into more meaning full domain objects,

```
def eventMapToEvent(eventMap: Map[String, String]): Option[Event] = {
  val subjectIdOpt = eventMap.get("id")
  val (titleOpt, descOpt) = (eventMap - "id").toList.headOption match {
    case Some((title, desc)) => (Some(title), Some(desc))
    case _ => (None, None)
  }

  (subjectIdOpt, titleOpt, descOpt) match {
    case (Some(subjectId), Some(title), Some(desc)) => Some(Event(subjectId, EventDetails(title, desc)))
    case _ => None
  }
}

val m1Events = m1.getOrElse("events", List()).flatMap(eventMapToEvent)
val m2Events = m2.getOrElse("events", List()).flatMap(eventMapToEvent)

val events = m1Events ++ m2Events
```

Now, the world will make more sense compared to dealing with maps. And we can proceed with the groupings.

```
val eventGroups = events.groupBy(event => event.subjectId).map({
  case (subjectId, eventList) => EventGroup(subjectId, eventList.map(event => event.eventDetails)).toList
})
// eventGroups: scala.collection.immutable.Iterable[EventGroup] = List(EventGroup(BeachBoys,List(EventDetails(desc,The second best band))), EventGroup(Elvis,List(EventDetails(when,Tomorrow))), EventGroup(Beatles,List(EventDetails(when,Today), EventDetails(desc,The greatest band))))
```

Comment: You answer is correct for this particular case, but as I stated, I'm interested in a generic approach.

Comment: Define "generic". This is a standard map/reduce requirement and both your `map` and `reduce` functions will always be specific, so I think you are looking for yet another simple map/reduce implementation.

Comment: You create a domain model via case classes. Hence, every time structural changes in the JSON source files occur, the source code needs to be adopted. As I want to use this kind of merge for a large variety of cases (where this Event domain is just one example), I want to merge the maps without any a priori structural knowledge with the exception that there might be an "id" field and if this present, first an intersection for this id and then a join should be computed. That is what I mean by "generic".

Comment: So I guess, the best way to achieve this, is to provide a proper Monoid Addition operation and then use combine (cats) / |+| (scalaz) but I am not sure how to do this.